# How to toggle a view based on a state in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a button `<Button> Log me in! </Button>`, and I would like to change its css class based on the state of my current vuex app. (`state.user` is not null)

What is the proper way to write this code?

I can create a field in the state that is the classname of this view and change that accordingly in actions/mutations. But are there better places that I should be placing this logic? As this field is completely component dependent, I don't think it should "leak" out to the global state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the typical object binding syntax.

```
<button :class={someClass: !$store.state.user}>Log me in!</button>
```

Or define a getter in Vuex and use that in your class definition.

Comment: i guess v-show is simpler but my question wasn't specific enough. This works! thanks

Comment: @user1017674 Sure, if you want to show/hide then `v-show` or `v-if` using the `state.user` is probably clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way is to use a computed function and bind a v-show directive that way.